# Airplane mode on at Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, hardware

I was helped to install Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS on Lenovo thinkpad 5ge something and it worked fine. But after the machine was turned off and on it displays Airplane mode on and demands to use hardware switch to turn it off. I tried:
sudo rfkill list all and got:
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
Then I tried: rfkill unblock 0
and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo rfkill unblock all; sudo ifconfig 0 down; sudo ifconfig 0 up; sudo iwconfig 0 mode managed
```

Comment: Got: sudo ifconfig 0 down
0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device --- But I checked it out -- still gives me 0 wlan phy0 hard blocked